# Get container in test class Symfony2

Tags: php, unit-testing, symfony, phpunit, containers

how I can get container to be able getting mys services in tests classes. I found the solution to `require_once dir(__FILE__). '/...../AppKernel.php;`, But when I go into `WebTestCase` class and found

```
protected static function createClient(array $options = array(), array $server = array())
{
    static::bootKernel($options);

    $client = static::$kernel->getContainer()->get('test.client');
    $client->setServerParameters($server);

    return $client;
}
```

Where Kernel booting, and another class `KernelTestCase` so I want to know I need to `require_once` AppKernel file or there is exist some more flexible and better method to get service container? Thanks!

Comment: @DOZ, no for now it extends from \PHPUnit_Framework_TestCase

Comment: you have to extend the WebTestCase so

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Example :

```
use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Test\WebTestCase;

class Test extends WebTestCase
{
   public function testCreate()
   {
      $client = static::$kernel->getContainer()->get('yourservice')
   }
}
```

Comment: actualy you forgot static::bootKernel(). :)